# How to pass variable containing Json data to Execute javascript Keyword

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I am trying to pass variable which contain json data to Execute javascript keyword in Robot Framework.

I tried

```
Execute Javascript   | var jsonData='${body}';
    ...              | var count=console.log(Object.keys(jsondata.segments).length);
```

but it is giving me TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: And you sure that the lowercase 'd' in `jsonData` is definitely not an issue here?

Comment: A `NoneType` object is a python object, not a javascript object, and that looks like a python error rather than a javascript error. Can you please show the full traceback? It sounds like the problem is somewhere before the javascript is executed.